# How can you debug a ServiceWorker if you close its tab (but leave the browser open)?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

If you close the page a `ServiceWorker` lives on but keep the browser open, I understand it should still be executing.  How do you debug it considering `console.log` messages are unavailable because the page is closed.

Comment: Could you write your "debug" values to localstorage and then check them?

Comment: Check this link, caching and cache storage https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/

Comment: do you know about the chrome urls to manage them? `chrome:serviceworker-internals`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chrome urls:  `chrome:serviceworker-internals`